# C++11 Initializing a std::string member

Tags: c++11

When I initialize the std::string member of a class calling its *C string* constructor, I receive the following errors:

```
error: expected identifier before string constant
error: expected ',' or '...' before string constant
```

Although, the program compiles successfully when I use copy initialization or list initialization.

```
class Element
{
private:
    std::string sName_("RandomName"); // Compile error
    std::string sName_ = "RandomName"; // OK
    std::string sName_{"RandomName"}; // OK
}
```

What seems to be the problem?

**UPDATE**

Now I realize this is a stupid question, because, as @p512 says, the compiler will see it as a erroneous method declaration. But I think this question should remain for other people that will do the same thinking error.

Comment: the error you are getting has nothing to do with this string, it complains about std::ifstream

Comment: Don't start with learning C++ with `std::string`, that's too difficult a concept. First start with `int` and see if you can [understand the situation](https://ideone.com/VWERBg) using only `int`s.

Comment: Reference: [http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init)

Comment: thanks for leaving this behind for others (me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::string sName_("RandomName");
```

This is an erroneous function declaration - at least that's what the compiler makes of it. Instead you can use something like this:

```
std::string sName_ = std::string("RandomName");
```

You can also use initializer lists in the constructor of your class:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : sName_("RandomName") {}
    std::string sName_;
};
```

You can find more on that here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: It's not a function declaration. If it was then it would compile. It's simply that use of parenthesis as an initializer are not allowed.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Which is why I used the attribute erroneous.
This is clang++'s output for such code:
main.cpp:8:14: error: expected parameter declarator

Comment: You called it a function declaration, which isn't an accurate description. It's actually just invalid syntax.

Comment: I think it could be a function declaration if there was no argument, i.e. `std::string sName_();`, but there is a string literal `"RandomName"` as an argument...